# How to inject environment variables from Groovy script in Jenkins piplenine

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need to migrate the freestyle project to the Jenkins pipeline. Any idea how to implement environment variable injection with groovy script to declarative pipeline?

I need pipeline code for this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can try add your groovy script into `environment`

```
environment {

 if() {
   env.xxx=yyy  // xxx is the name of environment variable
 }

}
```

Comment: @Dragan, are you aware of how to mark answers as correct when they solved an issue? I do not see a single answer marked by you, if you are unsure, simply click on the grey tick mark, left of the answer so it will turn green.